# Writing on Google SpreadSheet

Tags: java, google-sheets

I'm trying to follow this Google example - https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update.

However, when I run it returns an Unauthorized 401 error. In the link above, it says it requires one of the following OAuth scopes:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
```

Does anyone know how can I include these scopes in my java/gradle project?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add auth, because you need to be authenticated to perform the actions.

When authenticating you need to request the scopes (permissions) you want access to.

The Auth tutorial is available here [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2)